# What is the meaning and sense of 'bias' in NN?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm new to Neual Networks and I suppose I don't fully understand what 'bias' param does in Matlab's NN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means an additive term in the neuron computation.  Typically you have the input vector to a neuron `x`, and you perform a dot product with the weights, `w`.  Then you add on the bias term, `b` and apply a non-linear mapping.

The `b` number (per neuron) is part of the training and will change during training (unless you specifically disable it in training, but I know no reason to do this.)

The term *bias* is probably simply because it's an additive value in addition to the neuron's activation (that comes from the weighted inputs).  Once trained, the bias is a fixed term that does not depend on the neuron inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A neuron's bias is basically an extra input value that doesn't change. It is added to the normal inputs to get the total input to the neuron.