# pybrain poor results

Tags: python, neural-network, xor, pybrain

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if results are really that poor. Lets assume the simplest NN examples as shown in documentation:

```
>>>net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True)
>>> ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)
>>> ds.addSample((0, 0), (0,))
>>> ds.addSample((0, 1), (1,))
>>> ds.addSample((1, 0), (1,))
>>> ds.addSample((1, 1), (0,))
>>> trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
>>> trainer.trainUntilConvergence()
>>> print net.activate((0,0))
>>> print net.activate((0, 1))
>>> print net.activate((1, 0))
>>> print net.activate((1, 1))
```

e.g

```
>>> print net.activate((1,0))
[ 0.37855891]
>>> print net.activate((1,1))
[ 0.6592548]
```

Expected was 0. I know I can round obviously BUT still I would expect the network to be lot more precise for such a simple example. It can be called "working" here BUT I suspect I am missing something important cause this is VERY unusable...

The thing is that if you set `verbose=True` to your trainer you can see pretty small errors (like Total error: 0.0532936260399)

I would assume the error of the network is 5%, then how can it be SO MUCH off in activate function after that?

I use pybrain for a lot more complex thing obviously, but I have the same problem. I get roughly 50% of my test samples wrong even though the network says error is like 0.09 or so.

Any help pls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neural Network training with PyBrain won't converge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050460/neural-network-training-with-pybrain-wont-converge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050460/neural-network-training-with-pybrain-wont-converge). From there, it seems that this training function is not applicable here because not all data is used for training, but some data is used for cross-validation. Try adding the data points to the training set multiple times.

Also, this example seems to need to have a momentum term to work. There is an example for training an xor with pybrain, using a different training method [here](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/courses/cancomputersthink/assignments/week9_th/xor.py) which worked for me when I set the number of layers to 3. This uses a momentum term of 0.99.

I would post this as a comment because it doesn't answer the question fully, but I don't have enough points to comment...

Comment: you are right, I need to lessen the portion of data used for validation