# Export a neural network trained with MATLAB in other programming languages

Tags: matlab, neural-network, porting

I trained a neural network using the MATLAB Neural Network Toolbox, and in particular using the command `nprtool`, which provides a simple GUI to use the toolbox features, and to export a `net` object containing the informations about the NN generated.

In this way, I created a working neural network, that I can use as classifier, and a diagram representing it is the following:

[image: Diagram representing the Neural Network]

There are 200 inputs, 20 neurons in the first hidden layer, and 2 neurons in the last layer that provide a bidimensional output.

What I want to do is to use the network in some other programming language (C#, Java, ...).

In order to solve this problem, I try to use the following code in MATLAB:

```
y1 = tansig(net.IW{1} * input + net.b{1});
Results = tansig(net.LW{2} * y1 + net.b{2});
```

Assuming that `input` is a monodimensional array of 200 elements, the previous code would work if `net.IW{1}` is a 20x200 matrix (20 neurons, 200 weights).

The problem is that I noticed that `size(net.IW{1})` returns unexpected values:

```
>> size(net.IW{1})

    ans =

    20   199
```

I got the same problem with a network with 10000 input. In this case, the result wasn't 20x10000, but something like 20x9384 (I don't remember the exact value).

So, the question is: how can I obtain the weights of each neuron? And after that, can someone explain me how can I use them to produce the same output of MATLAB?

Comment: Some weights may have been set to 0, and therefore pruned from the matrix. Hopefully, if I'm correct, there is a setting somewhere to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I can't see any settings to change this kind of options... Can you help me to find them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved the problems described above, and I think it is useful to share what I've learned.

**Premises**

First of all, we need some definitions. Let's consider the following image, taken from [1]:

[image: A scheme of Neural Network]

In the above figure, **IW** stands for *initial weights*: they represent the **weights of neurons on the Layer 1**, each of which is connected with each input, as the following image shows [1]:

[image: All neurons are connected with all inputs]

All the other weights, are called *layer weights* (**LW** in the first figure), that are also connected with each output of the previous layer. In our case of study, we use a network with only two layers, so we will use only one LW array to solve our problems.

**Solution of the problem**

After the above introduction, we can proceed by dividing the issue in two steps:

- Force the number of initial weights to match with the input array length
- Use the weights to implement and use the neural network just trained in other programming languages

**A - Force the number of initial weights to match with the input array length**

Using the `nprtool`, we can train our network, and at the end of the process, we can also export in the workspace some information about the entire training process. In particular, we need to export:

- a MATLAB network object that represents the neural network created
- the input array used to train the network
- the target array used to train the network

Also, we need to generate a M-file that contains the code used by MATLAB to create the neural network, because we need to modify it and change some training options.

The following image shows how to perform these operations:

[image: The nprtool GUI to export data and generate the M-code]

The M-code generated will be similar to the following one:

```
function net = create_pr_net(inputs,targets)
%CREATE_PR_NET Creates and trains a pattern recognition neural network.
%
%  NET = CREATE_PR_NET(INPUTS,TARGETS) takes these arguments:
%    INPUTS - RxQ matrix of Q R-element input samples
%    TARGETS - SxQ matrix of Q S-element associated target samples, where
%      each column contains a single 1, with all other elements set to 0.
%  and returns these results:
%    NET - The trained neural network
%
%  For example, to solve the Iris dataset problem with this function:
%
%    load iris_dataset
%    net = create_pr_net(irisInputs,irisTargets);
%    irisOutputs = sim(net,irisInputs);
%
%  To reproduce the results you obtained in NPRTOOL:
%
%    net = create_pr_net(trainingSetInput,trainingSetOutput);

% Create Network
numHiddenNeurons = 20;  % Adjust as desired
net = newpr(inputs,targets,numHiddenNeurons);
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 75/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.testRatio = 10/100;  % Adjust as desired

% Train and Apply Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
outputs = sim(net,inputs);

% Plot
plotperf(tr)
plotconfusion(targets,outputs)
```

Before start the training process, we need to **remove all preprocessing and postprocessing functions** that MATLAB executes on inputs and outputs. This can be done adding the following lines just before the `% Train and Apply Network` lines:

```
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {};
```

After these changes to the `create_pr_net()` function, simply we can use it to create our final neural network:

```
net = create_pr_net(input, target);
```

where `input` and `target` are the values we exported through `nprtool`.

In this way, we are sure that the number of weights is equal to the length of input array. Also, this process is useful in order to simplify the porting to other programming languages.

**B - Implement and use the neural network just trained in other programming languages**

With these changes, we can define a function like this:

```
function [ Results ] = classify( net, input )
    y1 = tansig(net.IW{1} * input + net.b{1});

    Results = tansig(net.LW{2} * y1 + net.b{2});
end
```

In this code, we use the IW and LW arrays mentioned above, but also the *biases* b, used in the network schema by the `nprtool`. In this context, we don't care about the [role of biases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks); simply, we need to use them because `nprtool` does it.

Now, we can use the `classify()` function defined above, or the `sim()` function equally, obtaining the same results, as shown in the following example:

```
>> sim(net, input(:, 1))

ans =

    0.9759
   -0.1867
   -0.1891

>> classify(net, input(:, 1))

ans =

   0.9759   
  -0.1867
  -0.1891
```

Obviously, the `classify()` function can be interpreted as a pseudocode, and then implemented in every programming languages in which is possibile to define the MATLAB `tansig()` function [2] and the basic operations between arrays.

**References**

[1] [Howard Demuth, Mark Beale, Martin Hagan: *Neural Network Toolbox 6 - User Guide*, MATLAB](http://filer.case.edu/pjt9/b378s10/nnet.pdf)

[2] [Mathworks, *tansig - Hyperbolic tangent sigmoid transfer function*, MATLAB Documentation center](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/nnet/ref/tansig.html)

**Additional notes**

Take a look to the [robott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526112/export-a-neural-network-trained-with-matlab-in-other-programming-languages/21584220#21584220) and the [Sangeun Chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526112/export-a-neural-network-trained-with-matlab-in-other-programming-languages/23319086#23319086) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It helped me a lot. But i needed processFcns. I used only `[inputs,PSi] = mapminmax(inputs);` on my input data and saved it to minmaxParams.mat `save('minmaxParams','PSi')`. And then in my classify function i added  `load minmaxParams.mat;input = mapminmax('apply',input, PSi);`

Comment: I have merged all comments, corrected some typos, and gave an example implementation that works fine for a single hidden layer ANN. It includes Sangeun Chi's improvements and corrections.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small improvement to the great Vito Gentile's answer.

If you want to **use the preprocessing and postprocessing '*mapminmax*'** functions, you have to pay attention because 'mapminmax' in Matlab normalizes by ROW and not by column!

This is what you need to add to the upper "classify" function, to keep a coherent pre/post-processing:

```
[m n] = size(input);
ymax = 1;
ymin = -1;
for i=1:m
   xmax = max(input(i,:));
   xmin = min(input(i,:));
   for j=1:n
     input(i,j) = (ymax-ymin)*(input(i,j)-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) + ymin;
   end
end
```

And this at the end of the function:

```
ymax = 1;
ymin = 0;
xmax = 1;
xmin = -1;
Results = (ymax-ymin)*(Results-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) + ymin;
```

This is Matlab code, but it can be easily read as pseudocode.
Hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to VitoShadow and robott answers, I can export Matlab neural network values to other applications.

I really appreciate them, but I found some trivial errors in their codes and want to correct them.

1) In the VitoShadow codes,

```
Results = tansig(net.LW{2} * y1 + net.b{2});
-> Results = net.LW{2} * y1 + net.b{2};
```

2) In the robott preprocessing codes,
It would be easier extracting xmax and xmin from the net variable than calculating them.

```
xmax = net.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.xmax
xmin = net.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.xmin
```

3) In the robott postprocessing codes,

```
xmax = net.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.xmax
xmin = net.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.xmin

Results = (ymax-ymin)*(Results-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) + ymin;
-> Results = (Results-ymin)*(xmax-xmin)/(ymax-ymin) + xmin;
```

You can manually check and confirm the values as follows:

```
p2 = mapminmax('apply', net(:, 1), net.inputs{1}.processSettings{1})
```

-> preprocessed data

```
y1 = purelin ( net.LW{2} * tansig(net.iw{1}* p2 + net.b{1}) + net.b{2})
```

-> Neural Network processed data

```
y2 = mapminmax( 'reverse' , y1, net.outputs{2}.processSettings{1})
```

-> postprocessed data

Reference:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14517-processing-of-i-p-data

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement a simply 2-layer NN in C++ using OpenCV and then exported the weights to Android which worked quiet well. I wrote a small script which generates a header file with the learned weights and this is used in the following code snipped.

```
// Map Minimum and Maximum Input Processing Function
Mat mapminmax_apply(Mat x, Mat settings_gain, Mat settings_xoffset, double settings_ymin){

    Mat y;

    subtract(x, settings_xoffset, y);
    multiply(y, settings_gain, y);
    add(y, settings_ymin, y);

    return y;


    /* MATLAB CODE
     y = x - settings_xoffset;
     y = y .* settings_gain;
     y = y + settings_ymin;
     */
}




// Sigmoid Symmetric Transfer Function
Mat transig_apply(Mat n){
    Mat tempexp;
    exp(-2*n, tempexp);
    Mat transig_apply_result = 2 /(1 + tempexp) - 1;
    return transig_apply_result;
}


// Map Minimum and Maximum Output Reverse-Processing Function
Mat mapminmax_reverse(Mat y, Mat settings_gain, Mat settings_xoffset, double settings_ymin){

    Mat x;

    subtract(y, settings_ymin, x);
    divide(x, settings_gain, x);
    add(x, settings_xoffset, x);

    return x;


/* MATLAB CODE
function x = mapminmax_reverse(y,settings_gain,settings_xoffset,settings_ymin)
x = y - settings_ymin;
x = x ./ settings_gain;
x = x + settings_xoffset;
end
*/

}


Mat getNNParameter (Mat x1)
{

    // convert double array to MAT

    // input 1
    Mat x1_step1_xoffsetM = Mat(1, 48, CV_64FC1, x1_step1_xoffset).t();
    Mat x1_step1_gainM = Mat(1, 48, CV_64FC1, x1_step1_gain).t();
    double x1_step1_ymin = -1;

    // Layer 1
    Mat b1M = Mat(1, 25, CV_64FC1, b1).t();
    Mat IW1_1M = Mat(48, 25, CV_64FC1, IW1_1).t();

    // Layer 2
    Mat b2M = Mat(1, 48, CV_64FC1, b2).t();
    Mat LW2_1M = Mat(25, 48, CV_64FC1, LW2_1).t();

    // input 1
    Mat y1_step1_gainM = Mat(1, 48, CV_64FC1, y1_step1_gain).t();
    Mat y1_step1_xoffsetM = Mat(1, 48, CV_64FC1, y1_step1_xoffset).t();
    double y1_step1_ymin = -1;



    // ===== SIMULATION ========


    // Input 1
    Mat xp1 = mapminmax_apply(x1, x1_step1_gainM, x1_step1_xoffsetM, x1_step1_ymin);

    Mat  temp = b1M + IW1_1M*xp1;

    // Layer 1
    Mat a1M = transig_apply(temp);

    // Layer 2
    Mat a2M = b2M + LW2_1M*a1M;

    // Output 1
    Mat y1M = mapminmax_reverse(a2M, y1_step1_gainM, y1_step1_xoffsetM, y1_step1_ymin);

    return y1M;
}
```

example for a bias in the header could be this:

```
static double b2[1][48] = {
        {-0.19879, 0.78254, -0.87674, -0.5827, -0.017464, 0.13143, -0.74361, 0.4645, 0.25262, 0.54249, -0.22292, -0.35605, -0.42747, 0.044744, -0.14827, -0.27354, 0.77793, -0.4511, 0.059346, 0.29589, -0.65137, -0.51788, 0.38366, -0.030243, -0.57632, 0.76785, -0.36374, 0.19446, 0.10383, -0.57989, -0.82931, 0.15301, -0.89212, -0.17296, -0.16356, 0.18946, -1.0032, 0.48846, -0.78148, 0.66608, 0.14946, 0.1972, -0.93501, 0.42523, -0.37773, -0.068266, -0.27003, 0.1196}};
```

Now, that Google published Tensorflow, this became obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Hence the solution becomes (after correcting all parts)

Here I am giving a solution in Matlab, but if you have tanh() function, you may easily convert it to any programming language. It is for just showing the fields from network object and the operations you need.

- Assume you have a trained ann (network object) that you want to export
- Assume that the name of the trained ann is trained_ann

Here is the script for exporting and testing.
Testing script compares original network result with my_ann_evaluation() result

```
% Export IT
exported_ann_structure = my_ann_exporter(trained_ann);

% Run and Compare 
% Works only for single INPUT vector
% Please extend it to MATRIX version by yourself
input = [12 3 5 100];
res1 = trained_ann(input')';
res2 = my_ann_evaluation(exported_ann_structure, input')';
```

where you need the following two functions

*First my_ann_exporter*:

```
function [ my_ann_structure ] = my_ann_exporter(trained_netw)
% Just for extracting as Structure object
my_ann_structure.input_ymax = trained_netw.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.ymax;
my_ann_structure.input_ymin = trained_netw.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.ymin;
my_ann_structure.input_xmax = trained_netw.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.xmax;
my_ann_structure.input_xmin = trained_netw.inputs{1}.processSettings{1}.xmin;

my_ann_structure.IW = trained_netw.IW{1};
my_ann_structure.b1 = trained_netw.b{1};
my_ann_structure.LW = trained_netw.LW{2};
my_ann_structure.b2 = trained_netw.b{2};

my_ann_structure.output_ymax = trained_netw.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.ymax;
my_ann_structure.output_ymin = trained_netw.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.ymin;
my_ann_structure.output_xmax = trained_netw.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.xmax;
my_ann_structure.output_xmin = trained_netw.outputs{2}.processSettings{1}.xmin;
end
```

*Second my_ann_evaluation:*

```
function [ res ] = my_ann_evaluation(my_ann_structure, input)
% Works with only single INPUT vector
% Matrix version can be implemented

ymax = my_ann_structure.input_ymax;
ymin = my_ann_structure.input_ymin;
xmax = my_ann_structure.input_xmax;
xmin = my_ann_structure.input_xmin;
input_preprocessed = (ymax-ymin) * (input-xmin) ./ (xmax-xmin) + ymin;

% Pass it through the ANN matrix multiplication
y1 = tanh(my_ann_structure.IW * input_preprocessed + my_ann_structure.b1);

y2 = my_ann_structure.LW * y1 + my_ann_structure.b2;

ymax = my_ann_structure.output_ymax;
ymin = my_ann_structure.output_ymin;
xmax = my_ann_structure.output_xmax;
xmin = my_ann_structure.output_xmin;
res = (y2-ymin) .* (xmax-xmin) /(ymax-ymin) + xmin;
end
```

Comment: This exporting function is designed for a simple case: only for an ANN with 1input, 1output, and 1hidden layer. One can easily extend it to more layered ANNs