# how to load deep learning model, trained in matlab, in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a deep learning model trained in matlab and it is available in .mat format, How can i use this file for prediction in python environment?

I tried `scipy.io.loadmat(filename.mat)` but getting some errors

Comment: so how about sharing those erros?
maybe     scipy.io.loadmat('filename.mat') ?

Comment: In it's current form, your question is too broad. Here is a possible duplicate, and also an example of a well structured question: [Export a neural network trained with MATLAB in other programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526112/export-a-neural-network-trained-with-matlab-in-other-programming-languages)

Answer (score 0):

One option for you might be to export the model from MATLAB to ONYX. From there, you should be able to use the result in any deep learning framework that supports ONYX, or move from from the ONYX representation to something supported in your framework of choice.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/exportonnxnetwork.html

Comment: i am using matlab R2019b. will it work for this version?