# In training a neural network, must you include a bias?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I'm actually working on answering this question (from an [examination](http://www.mainlib.uwi.tt//exams/Papers/pdfpapers/c_99/comp6600_1_11.pdf)):

> Show in tabular form the first five epochs of the training of a
>   perceptron to perform the Boolean OR operation; using initial weights
>   of 0.3 and -0.2; a threshold value of 0.2; and the learning rate of
>   0.1

I've produced an answer here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqDm6Izoam4OdF9sWXNQT0FqOF90UWpTeC1LdTd4VUE&output=html

But unlike the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Example) in Wikipedia, I haven't included a bias. Is it necessary?

Comment: Looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks, no, I don't think you HAVE to have it

Comment: Hmm on wiki bias = 0, what do you say they use a bias?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, "Inputs: x0, x1, x2,  with input x0  held constant at 1."

Comment: @Irwin Thanks, I had missed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't *need* to have a bias node in your neural network - many networks can still converge to a solution without one. However, given that neural network convergence can sometimes be finicky, having a bias node is generally a good idea. Essentially, as discussed here [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks), it gives the neural net a way to adjust how high an activation level needs to be in order for a node to fire. It's kind of conceptually similar to including a y-intercept in a line equation.