# threshold and bias in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, terminology

I'm a newbie..I don't understand why we use threshold and bias in MLP (`Multi-Layer Perceptron`)??What is the role of threshold, bias..And I don't know the formula of output (the result after we use the activation function, such as sigmoid) follow bias and threshold..In the same document, I see:

```
output_value=activation_function(summing_function+threshold) (follow Jeff Heaton)
output_value=activation_function(summing_function-threshold)(follow my teacher)
output_value=activation_function(summing_function+bias) (no problem!)
```

Which is the correct??Please give me a response!

And, the bias and the threshold can exists same time in MLP??

Comment: An excellent answer to this question has already been given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2499936/1772556).

Answer (score 8):

**bias** and **threshold** in MLP are the same concepts, simply - two different names for the same thing. Sign does not matter, as **bias** can be both positive and negative (but it is more common to use **+ bias**).

In the most simple terms - if there is no bias, then for input of only `0`'s, you get `summing_function=0`, and as a result also `output_value=0` (as most of the activation functions cross the origin). As a result, your network cannot learn any other behavior for this type of signal, as only changing part of the whole model are **weights**.

From more mathematical perspective - this is responsible for shifting the activation function and giving neural network the **universal approximator** capabilities.