# Trouble Understanding the Backpropagation Algorithm in Neural Network

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm having trouble understanding the backpropagation algorithm. I read a lot and searched a lot but I can't understand why my Neural Network don't work. I want to confirm that I'm doing every part the right way.

Here is my Neural Network when it is initialize and when the first line of inputs [1, 1] and the output [0] is set (as you can see, I'm trying to do the XOR Neural Network) :

[image: My Neural Network]

I have 3 layers : input, hidden and output. The first layer (input) and the hidden layer contains 2 neurons in which there is 2 synapses each. The last layer (output) contains one neuron with 2 synapses too.

A synapse contains a weight and it’s previous delta (at the beginning, it is 0). The output connected to the synapse can be found with the sourceNeuron associated with the synapse or in the inputs array if there is no sourceNeuron (like in the input layer).

The class **Layer.java** contains a list of neurons. In my **NeuralNetwork.java**, I initialize the Neural Network then I loop in my training set. In each iteration, I replace the inputs and the output values and call train on my BackPropagation Algorithm and the algorithm run certain number of time (epoch of 1000 times for now) for the current set.

The **activation** fonction I use is the sigmoid.

Training set AND validation set is (input1, input2, output):

```
1,1,0
0,1,1
1,0,1
0,0,0
```

Here is my **Neuron.java** implementation:

```
public class Neuron {

    private IActivation activation;
    private ArrayList<Synapse> synapses; // Inputs
    private double output; // Output
    private double errorToPropagate;

    public Neuron(IActivation activation) {
        this.activation = activation;
        this.synapses = new ArrayList<Synapse>();
        this.output = 0;
        this.errorToPropagate = 0;
    }

    public void updateOutput(double[] inputs) {
        double sumWeights = this.calculateSumWeights(inputs);

        this.output = this.activation.activate(sumWeights);
    }

    public double calculateSumWeights(double[] inputs) {
        double sumWeights = 0;

        int index = 0;
        for (Synapse synapse : this.getSynapses()) {
            if (inputs != null) {
                sumWeights += synapse.getWeight() * inputs[index];
            } else {
                sumWeights += synapse.getWeight() * synapse.getSourceNeuron().getOutput();
            }

            index++;
        }

        return sumWeights;
    }

    public double getDerivative() {
        return this.activation.derivative(this.output);
    }

    [...]
}
```

The **Synapse.java** contains:

```
public Synapse(Neuron sourceNeuron) {
    this.sourceNeuron = sourceNeuron;
    Random r = new Random();
    this.weight = (-0.5) + (0.5 - (-0.5)) * r.nextDouble();
    this.delta = 0;
}

[... getter and setter ...]
```

The **train** method in my class **BackpropagationStrategy.java** run a while loop and stop after 1000 times (epoch) with one line of the training set. It looks like this:

```
this.forwardPropagation(neuralNetwork, inputs);

this.backwardPropagation(neuralNetwork, expectedOutput);

this.updateWeights(neuralNetwork);
```

Here is all the implementation of the methods above (learningRate = 0.45 and momentum = 0.9):

```
public void forwardPropagation(NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork, double[] inputs) {

    for (Layer layer : neuralNetwork.getLayers()) {

        for (Neuron neuron : layer.getNeurons()) {
            if (layer.isInput()) {
                neuron.updateOutput(inputs);
            } else {
                neuron.updateOutput(null);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void backwardPropagation(NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork, double realOutput) {

    Layer lastLayer = null;

    // Loop à travers les hidden layers et le output layer uniquement
    ArrayList<Layer> layers = neuralNetwork.getLayers();
    for (int i = layers.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        Layer layer = layers.get(i);

        for (Neuron neuron : layer.getNeurons()) {

            double errorToPropagate = neuron.getDerivative();

            // Output layer
            if (layer.isOutput()) {

                errorToPropagate *= (realOutput - neuron.getOutput());
            }
            // Hidden layers
            else {
                double sumFromLastLayer = 0;

                for (Neuron lastLayerNeuron : lastLayer.getNeurons()) {
                    for (Synapse synapse : lastLayerNeuron.getSynapses()) {
                        if (synapse.getSourceNeuron() == neuron) {
                            sumFromLastLayer += (synapse.getWeight() * lastLayerNeuron.getErrorToPropagate());

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                errorToPropagate *= sumFromLastLayer;
            }

            neuron.setErrorToPropagate(errorToPropagate);
        }

        lastLayer = layer;
    }
}

public void updateWeights(NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork) {

    for (int i = neuralNetwork.getLayers().size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {

        Layer layer = neuralNetwork.getLayers().get(i);

        for (Neuron neuron : layer.getNeurons()) {

            for (Synapse synapse : neuron.getSynapses()) {

                double delta = this.learningRate * neuron.getError() * synapse.getSourceNeuron().getOutput();

                synapse.setWeight(synapse.getWeight() + delta + this.momentum * synapse.getDelta());

                synapse.setDelta(delta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the validation set, I only run this:

```
this.forwardPropagation(neuralNetwork, inputs);
```

And then check the output of the neuron in my output layer.

Did I do something wrong? Need some explanations...

Here are my results after 1000 epoch:

```
Real: 0.0
Current: 0.025012156926937503
Real: 1.0
Current: 0.022566830709341495
Real: 1.0
Current: 0.02768416343491415
Real: 0.0
Current: 0.024903432706154027
```

Why the synapses in the input layer are not updated? Everywhere it is written to only update the hidden and output layers.

Like you can see, it is totally wrong! It doesn't go to the 1.0 only to the first train set output (0.0).

**UPDATE 1**

Here is one iteration over the network with this set: [1.0,1.0,0.0]. Here is the result for the forward propagation method:

```
=== Input Layer

== Neuron #1

= Synapse #1
Weight: -0.19283583155573614
Input: 1.0

= Synapse #2
Weight: 0.04023817185601586
Input: 1.0

Sum: -0.15259765969972028
Output: 0.461924442180935

== Neuron #2

= Synapse #1
Weight: -0.3281099260608612
Input: 1.0

= Synapse #2
Weight: -0.4388250065958519
Input: 1.0

Sum: -0.7669349326567131
Output: 0.31714251453174147

=== Hidden Layer

== Neuron #1

= Synapse #1
Weight: 0.16703288052854093
Input: 0.461924442180935

= Synapse #2
Weight: 0.31683996162148054
Input: 0.31714251453174147

Sum: 0.17763999229679783
Output: 0.5442935820534444

== Neuron #2

= Synapse #1
Weight: -0.45330313978424686
Input: 0.461924442180935

= Synapse #2
Weight: 0.3287014377113835
Input: 0.31714251453174147

Sum: -0.10514659949771789
Output: 0.47373754172497556

=== Output Layer

== Neuron #1

= Synapse #1
Weight: 0.08643751629154495
Input: 0.5442935820534444

= Synapse #2
Weight: -0.29715579267218695
Input: 0.47373754172497556

Sum: -0.09372646936373039
Output: 0.47658552081912403
```

**Update 2**

I probably have a bias problem. I will look into it with the help of this answer: [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks). It doesn't shift back at the next dataset so...

Comment: You use confusing names for your functions and variables. At its least, it makes your code hard to understand, and at most, it suggests that you have still some lacks in understanding the algorithm. For example you use `this.error` to store the output's derivative multiplied by the error (so it's the value of the error to propagate, not the error in this neuron). `calculateSumWeights` also seems wrong: this function doesn't calculate the sum of the weights for sure. Try to tidy up your code, and use a debugger with a very simple data set (one or two examples, with one or two attributes).

Comment: Should I call The error propagation of the neuron a threshold? What is the name? It can help me find some answer. I will look into the sum method but do you saw somerhing wrong about it?

Comment: I'm sure that if anyone spots the mistake they will surely let you know, no need to ask about it again. However, as I've mentioned it is hard to diagnose other people's code by just looking at it. Especially when it comes to such complicated things as neural networks. Please try to use the debugger and narrow the problem, perhaps using the approach I've recommended in my previous comment (I didn't notice your training set is already simple - so it's all right, and it should be very easy to see when a neuron's output should be moved towards 1 and it goes closer to 0 instead).

Comment: Ok thank you I'll look closely to it. How would you call the neuron's error propagation? I'm a bit confused about the terms such as delta, bias, gradient, threshold, etc. You can probably clear that a bit for me it would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't remember I ever needed to store this value, IIRC it is only needed once for the purpose of propagation and calculating the delta values. However, perhaps in your version it is needed. I would call the propagated error .... `propagatedError` :) In your case (however please note that I may have misunderstood your code), it seems like it's more the error to be propagated to the previous layer, so perhaps it's not "propagated error" but "error to propagate". In which case I would call it ... (surprise!) `errorToPropagate`.

Comment: I modified the name and my Neuron class. The derivative was only apply on the output layer and not the hidden layers. Also, I found an error where I didn't link correctly my hidden and output layer. I now have better results but it always go to the first output of the first set... I will investigate a little further!

Comment: I added the result of the forward propagation. Seems fine to me!

Comment: Do you select the input sample randomly? If not, you could try it - perhaps it will help a bit.

Comment: I train with the four possible XOR set, but I can try. I put a second update too. I think I have a bias problem. I thought it was use only for linear activation not with sigmoid.

Comment: Bias is essential to solve the XOR problem. Without bias all your separation planes (lines) go through the origin. Impossible to separate (0,0) from (0,1) like this for example.

Comment: Ok I'll try that this afternoon! I hope it will work (probably). Thank you! I'll put on an update. I will probably need more help afterward with the real datas which is 11 inputs and 1 output each set with value from 0 to 200.

Comment: Please focus on one issue per post, this site is not a help-desk service. After this issue is resolved an answer post should be added and accepted, so it may help future visitors.

Comment: Yes of course. If it works, post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: You've managed to solve most of it by yourself, so you could also move the updates from the question to your self-answer and also accept it.

Comment: you might be interested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38767930/5082406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. For the XOR, I didn't need any bias and it was converging to the expected values. I got exactly the output when you round the final output. What was needed is to train then validate, then train again until the Neural Network is satisfaying. I was training each set until satisfaction but not the WHOLE set again and again.

```
// Initialize the Neural Network
algorithm.initialize(this.numberOfInputs);

int index = 0;
double errorRate = 0;

// Loop until satisfaction or after some iterations
do {
    // Train the Neural Network
    algorithm.train(this.trainingDataSets, this.numberOfInputs);

    // Validate the Neural Network and return the error rate
    errorRate = algorithm.run(this.validationDataSets, this.numberOfInputs);

    index++;
} while (errorRate > minErrorRate && index < numberOfTrainValidateIteration);
```

With the real datas, I need a bias because the outputs started to diverge. Here is how I added the bias:

In **Neuron.java** class, I added a bias synapse with a weight and an output of 1.0. I sum it with all the other synapses then put it in my activation function.

```
public class Neuron implements Serializable {

    [...]

    private Synapse bias;

    public Neuron(IActivation activation) {
        [...]
        this.bias = new Synapse(this);
        this.bias.setWeight(0.5); // Set initial weight OR keep the random number already set
    }

    public void updateOutput(double[] inputs) {
        double sumWeights = this.calculateSumWeights(inputs);

        this.output = this.activation.activate(sumWeights + this.bias.getWeight() * 1.0);
    }

    [...]
```

In **BackPropagationStrategy.java**, I change the weight and the delta of each bias in the updateWeights method that I renamed updateWeightsAndBias.

```
public class BackPropagationStrategy implements IStrategy, Serializable {

    [...]

    public void updateWeightsAndBias(NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork, double[] inputs) {

        for (int i = neuralNetwork.getLayers().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            Layer layer = neuralNetwork.getLayers().get(i);

            for (Neuron neuron : layer.getNeurons()) {

                [...]

                Synapse bias = neuron.getBias();
                double delta = learning * 1.0;
                bias.setWeight(bias.getWeight() + delta + this.momentum * bias.getDelta());

                bias.setDelta(delta);
            }
        }
    }

    [...]
```

With the real datas, the Network is converging. It is now a pruning job to find the perfect variables combo (if it is possible) of learning rate, momentum, error rate, quantity of neurons, quantity of hidden layers, etc.