# TensorFlow Dense Layers: 1 dimentional weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have my network set up in the following fashion:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

I would expect this configuration to be like this:

```
[784 neurons]
(784,128 weights)
[128 neurons]
(128,10 weights)
[10 neurons]
```

But, when I print the network's weights with model.get_weights(), it produces the following output:

```
for w in model.get_weights():
    print(w.shape,"\n")
```

> (784, 128)
>
> (128,)
>
> (128, 10)
>
> (10,)

Why do (128,) and (10,) exist in this model?

Comment: `(784, 128)` and `(128, 10)` are the last two layers of **weights**. `(128,)` and `(10,)` are the last two layers of **biases**.

Comment: @giser_yugang Oh, I forgot about biases! Does this mean every node in a dense layer has a bias?

Comment: I just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000215/neural-net-bias-per-layer-or-per-node-non-input-node, and it helped me understand. Thanks for the helpful comment!

Comment: Yes. But you can also use `use_bias` parameter to set it .

Comment: @giser_yugang I kindly suggest you post this as an answer

Comment: Someone downvoted and requested this question to be closed. How can I improve the phrasing of the question to make it better?

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you for your advice. I added it as an answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(784, 128)` and `(128, 10)` are the last two layers **weights**. `(128,)` and `(10,)` are the last two layers **biases**. If you don't need **biases**, you can use `use_bias` parameter to set it. For example:

```
import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, use_bias=False,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, use_bias=False,activation='softmax')
])

for w in model.get_weights():
    print(w.shape,"\n")

# print
(784, 128) 

(128, 10)
```