# Neural Network returning same output for every input

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have written a simple Artificial Neural Network in Java as part of a project. When I begin training the data (Using a training set i gathered) The error count in each epoch quickly stabilizes (to around 30% accuracy) and then stops. When testing the ANN all outputs for any given input are EXACTLY the same.

I am trying to output a number between 0 and 1 (0 to classify a stock as a faller and 1 to classify a riser - 0.4-0.6 should indicate stability)

When adding the same training data into RapidMiner Studios a proper ANN with much greater (70+%) Accuracy is created, therefore I know that the dataset is fine. There must be some problem in the ANN logic.

Below is the code for running and adjusting the weights. Any and all help appreciated!

```
    public double[] Run(double[] inputs) {
    //INPUTS
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.length; i++) {
        inputNeurons[i] = inputs[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenNeurons.length; i++) {
        hiddenNeurons[i] = 0;
    } //RESET THE HIDDEN NEURONS

    for (int e = 0; e < inputNeurons.length; e++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenNeurons.length; i++) {
            //Looping through each input neuron connected to each hidden neuron

            hiddenNeurons[i] += inputNeurons[e] * inputWeights[(e * hiddenNeurons.length) + i];
            //Summation (with the adding of neurons)  - Done by taking the sum of each (input * connection weight)
            //The more weighting a neuron has the more "important" it is in decision making
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < hiddenNeurons.length; j++) {
        hiddenNeurons[j] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-hiddenNeurons[j]));
        //sigmoid function transforms the output into a real number between 0 and 1
    }

    //HIDDEN
    for (int i = 0; i < outputNeurons.length; i++) {
        outputNeurons[i] = 0;
    } //RESET THE OUTPUT NEURONS

    for (int e = 0; e < hiddenNeurons.length; e++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < outputNeurons.length; i++) {
            //Looping through each hidden neuron connected to each output neuron

            outputNeurons[i] += hiddenNeurons[e] * hiddenWeights[(e * outputNeurons.length) + i];
            //Summation (with the adding of neurons) as above
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < outputNeurons.length; j++) {
        outputNeurons[j] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-outputNeurons[j])); //sigmoid function as above
    }

    double[] outputs = new double[outputNeurons.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < outputNeurons.length; j++) {
        //Places all output neuron values into an array
        outputs[j] = outputNeurons[j];
    }
    return outputs;
}

public double[] CalculateErrors(double[] targetValues) {
    //Compares the given values to the actual values
    for (int k = 0; k < outputErrors.length; k++) {
        outputErrors[k] = targetValues[k] - outputNeurons[k];
    }
    return outputErrors;
}

    public void tuneWeights() //Back Propagation
{
    // Start from the end - From output to hidden
    for (int p = 0; p < this.hiddenNeurons.length; p++)     //For all Hidden Neurons
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < this.outputNeurons.length; q++)  //For all Output Neurons
        {
            double delta = this.outputNeurons[q] * (1 - this.outputNeurons[q]) * this.outputErrors[q];
            //DELTA is the error for the output neuron q
            this.hiddenWeights[(p * outputNeurons.length) + q] += this.learningRate * delta * this.hiddenNeurons[p];
            /*Adjust the particular weight relative to the error
             *If the error is large, the weighting will be decreased
             *If the error is small, the weighting will be increased
             */
        }
    }

    // From hidden to inps -- Same as above
    for (int i = 0; i < this.inputNeurons.length; i++)       //For all Input Neurons
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.hiddenNeurons.length; j++)  //For all Hidden Neurons
        {
            double delta = this.hiddenNeurons[j] * (1 - this.hiddenNeurons[j]);
            double x = 0;       //We do not have output errors here so we must use extra data from Output Neurons
            for (int k = 0; k < this.outputNeurons.length; k++) {
                double outputDelta = this.outputNeurons[k] * (1 - this.outputNeurons[k]) * this.outputErrors[k];
                //We calculate the output delta again
                x = x + outputDelta * this.hiddenWeights[(j * outputNeurons.length) + k];
                //We then calculate the error based on the hidden weights (x is used to add the error values of all weights)
                delta = delta * x;
            }
            this.inputWeights[(i * hiddenNeurons.length) + j] += this.learningRate * delta * this.inputNeurons[i];
            //Adjust weight like above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize weights? Aren't they all 0 in the begining?

Comment: Tried that with the same results, at the moment  they are being randomly initialized between -1 and 1

Comment: Beacuse if you initialize them all with 0s you may get such effect (that your network will simply stuck in this configuration). Is it working now (after random initialization)?

Comment: No :/ exact same results. I can't understand how all inputs cause the same outputs

Comment: And what kind of outputs do you get? Are you 100% that weights are not initialized to 0?

Comment: I am 100% sure, I even added a check which doesn't allow 0, and another one where it doesn't allow values between 0 and 0.05. Both secnarios didn't work

Comment: And what are those outputs which you get every time?

Comment: it's different every time I train the neural net
I just ran it now to check for you - the outputs all came between 0.44 and 0.47 as you can see here where is written | OUT - https://gyazo.com/a9f923a33deeb64188d0355db6950fa4 

This is slightly better than previous results

Comment: How long have you trained this model? What was the learning rate? Have you used the additional bias term? This screen shows that your model might be bad.

Comment: I'm using the following -
7 Hidden neurons (Tried all amounts from 3-8), Learning rate of .25 which decreases to .2 after a number of epochs, and no I have not used bias

I do suspect that there is a logical problem in my model

Comment: But Dude - not using bias is reeeaaaally bad idea. You also have to babysit your learning process.

Comment: Okay, so what would I have to do to add a bias, I've heard it's useful but this is my first attempt at anything AI related

Answer (score 2):

After long coversation I think that you may find an answer to your question in the following points :

1. Bias is really important. Actually - one of the most popular SO questions about neural network is about bias :) :
   [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks?rq=1)
2. You should babysit your learning process. It's good to keep track of your test on accuracy and validation set and to use appropriate learning rate during training. What I advise you is to use simpler dataset when you know that it is easy to find true solution (for example - a triangle or square - use 4 - 5 hidden units then). I also advise you to use the following playgroud :

http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.36368&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification