# Keras model.summary function displays incosistent output format

Tags: python, keras

I am studying the in and outs of Keras. So, in this aspect I was checking the `model.summary()` function.

I was using a simple [image classification example](https://keras.io/applications/) provided by Keras itself and loaded the various pretrained models provided (Xception, VGG16 etc).

I checked each model architecture using `model.summary()` as mentioned. Then I noticed that for some reason the column `Connected to` (4th column that is) is not present to every model summary. For example for `MobileNetV2` I get (just the first few lines are shown):

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 225, 225, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 112, 112, 32) 864         Conv1_pad[0][0]
```

but for `MobileNet` I get:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 225, 225, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 112, 112, 32)      864
```

This output is performed without taking any extra action after the model loading (no training, neither inference etc).

This seems odd and I am not sure what's going on here. For example when creating this simple model from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946671/keras-model-summary-result-understanding-the-of-parameters) (up to the `model0.fit(...)` part) and running `model0.summary()` gives me a summary without `Connected to` column also contrary to the posted summary in this question.

So, this change to the output? What's the deal with `model.summary()`? Do we have some control over the output (although the examples above do not imply that)? Or the output has to do with the way a model was structured?

Edit:

I added the (trivial) code used to reproduce the summary of both models as requested in a comment.

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet

model1 = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')
print(model1.summary())
model2 = MobileNet(weights='imagenet')
print(model2.summary())
```

Also, my system uses Keras 2.2.4, Tensorflow 1.12.0 and Ubuntu 16.04 if these info are useful somehow.

Comment: You should include the actual code that produces both results, including imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the reason is: `MobileNetV2` was implemented `keras.Model`, but MobileNet is `keras.Sequential`.

Both `Model` and `Sequential` have a `summary` method. While running, it invokes [`print_summary`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L24) method, which acts differently for sequential-like and non-sequential models:

```
if sequential_like:
    line_length = line_length or 65
    positions = positions or [.45, .85, 1.]
    if positions[-1] <= 1:
        positions = [int(line_length * p) for p in positions]
    # header names for the different log elements
    to_display = ['Layer (type)', 'Output Shape', 'Param #']
else:
    line_length = line_length or 98
    positions = positions or [.33, .55, .67, 1.]
    if positions[-1] <= 1:
        positions = [int(line_length * p) for p in positions]
    # header names for the different log elements
    to_display = ['Layer (type)',
                  'Output Shape',
                  'Param #',
                  'Connected to']
    relevant_nodes = []
    for v in model._nodes_by_depth.values():
        relevant_nodes += v
```

([link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L75)). As you can see, it just doesn't print `'Connected to'` for a sequential-like model.
I guess the reason is that sequential model doesn't allow to connect layers in non-sequential order - so, they just connected one-by-one.

Also, it checks a model type via `model.__class__.__name__ == 'Sequential'` ([link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L43)). I doubt that it's a good idea trying to cahnge it "on-the-fly" to obtain a different output.

Comment: Yeah you are right but 2 observations: 1) API should have been different in the past because the question I referenced used a `Sequential ` model and it printed `Connected to` and 2) it seems that Keras check for actual non-sequential state (even if model is chosen) before displaying `Connected to`.

Comment: You're right, it's my mistake, I was inattentive. Actually `print_summary` can treat this way not only the `Sequential`, but any model without complex-connected layers - [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L53) and above this line placed type-selection logic. Probably I'll edit my answer