# Why is a simple 2-layer Neural Network unable to learn 0,0 sequence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

While going through the [example](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/27/python-network-part2/) of a tiny 2-layer neural network I noticed the result that I cannot explain.

Imagine we have the following dataset with the corresponding labels:

```
[0,1] -> [0]
[0,1] -> [0]
[1,0] -> [1]
[1,0] -> [1]
```

Let's create a tiny 2-layer NN which will learn to predict the outcome of a two number sequence where each number can be 0 or 1. We shall train this NN given our dataset mentioned above.

```py
    import numpy as np

    # compute sigmoid nonlinearity
    def sigmoid(x):
        output = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return output

    # convert output of sigmoid function to its derivative
    def sigmoid_to_deriv(output):
        return output * (1 - output)

    def predict(inp, weigths):
        print inp, sigmoid(np.dot(inp, weigths))

    # input dataset
    X = np.array([ [0,1],
                   [0,1],
                   [1,0],
                   [1,0]])
    # output dataset
    Y = np.array([[0,0,1,1]]).T

    np.random.seed(1)

    # init weights randomly with mean 0
    weights0 = 2 * np.random.random((2,1)) - 1

    for i in xrange(10000):
        # forward propagation
        layer0 = X
        layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, weights0))
        # compute the error
        layer1_error = layer1 - Y

        # gradient descent
        # calculate the slope at current x position
        layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid_to_deriv(layer1)
        weights0_deriv = np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
        # change x by the negative of the slope (x = x - slope)
        weights0 -= weights0_deriv

    print 'INPUT   PREDICTION'
    predict([0,1], weights0)
    predict([1,0], weights0)
    # test prediction of the unknown data
    predict([1,1], weights0)
    predict([0,0], weights0)
```

After we've trained this NN we test it.

```
INPUT   PREDICTION
[0, 1] [ 0.00881315]
[1, 0] [ 0.99990851]
[1, 1] [ 0.5]
[0, 0] [ 0.5]
```

Ok, `0,1` and `1,0` is what we would expect. The predictions for `0,0` and `1,1` are also explainable, our NN just didn't have the training data for these cases, so let's add it into our training dataset:

```
[0,1] -> [0]
[0,1] -> [0]
[1,0] -> [1]
[1,0] -> [1]
[0,0] -> [0]
[1,1] -> [1]
```

Retrain the network and test it again!

```
INPUT   PREDICTION
[0, 1] [ 0.00881315]
[1, 0] [ 0.99990851]
[1, 1] [ 0.9898148]
[0, 0] [ 0.5]
```

- Wait, why **[0,0]** is still **0.5**?

This means that NN is **still** uncertain about `0,0`, same when it was uncertain about `1,1` until we trained it.

Comment: I think this model is corect. The net was able to distinct sucessfully the data. You can now just add an threshold to classify the data.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, you have no bias units. A hunch, but I feel like in this example, feeding in [0,0] without a bias unit will result in problems. Since its a small network, you could fix this by appending 1's to the end of each training example and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The classification is right as well. You need to understand that the net was able to separate the test set.

Now You need to use an step function to classify the data between `0` or `1`.

In your case the `0.5` seems to be a good `threshold`

**EDIT:**

You need to add the bias to the code.

```
# input dataset
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],
               [0,0,1],
               [0,1,0],
               [0,1,0]])

# init weights randomly with mean 0
weights0 = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1
```

Comment: Yep, add a bias, if you want an explanation of why, think about what happens to an input of [0,0] in a neural network with no bias units. Since a neural network is performing multiplication between each layer, the weights have no impact, since any number times 0 is still 0. So, at the final layer, the activation of each  node is 0, and when a zero gets passed to the sigmoid function, it outputs .5, which is what your net was outputing.