# What is the interest to add bias to Softmax function in the case of CNNs?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I would like to know what is the interest to add bias *b* to Softmax function in the case of CNNs

[image]

Comment: Your question needs some refinement. The equation you're showing ( you should type it, not link to images) is showing a fully connected network operation, not a CNN. And neither of these seem to be directly related to softmax in the context of your questoin. Could you update your question with more detail please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you linked is a standard affine transformation preceding the application of a pointwise nonlinearity, **not** the softmax activation function itself. If you'd like to know why a bias term is used in neural networks, please refer to this post: [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)

Comment: Is the affine transformation just applied before the soft-max function? What is the goal to use affine transformation before a softmax function?

Comment: The softmax function deterministically maps unscaled logits(the output of the affine transformation) to normalized probability distributions. Thus, the predictions emitted by a softmax activation function can be interpreted as class probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help.