# How to gain acces to the bias and weights in ML.NET?

Tags: c#, neural-network, linear-regression, ml.net

Ive got a linear regression model in ML.NET and the predictions are working fine:

```
  MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
            List<TwoInputRegressionModel> inputs = new List<TwoInputRegressionModel>();
            foreach (var JahrMitCO in ListWithCO)
            {
                float tempyear = JahrMitCO.Year;
                foreach (var JahrMitPopulation in Population)
                {
                    if (JahrMitPopulation.Year == tempyear)
                    {
                        inputs.Add(new TwoInputRegressionModel() { Year = tempyear, Population = JahrMitPopulation.Value, Co2 = JahrMitCO.Value });
                    }
                }
            }
            var model = Train(mlContext, inputs);
            TestSinglePrediction(mlContext, model); //works
```

But I would like to know how to gain access to the parameters (weights + bias) of the trained model? I do know that the ITransformer class (here called model)does contain a Model property, but trying to convert it to the LinearRegressionModelParameters class like stated on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/train-machine-learning-model-ml-net) doesnt work:

```
 LinearRegressionModelParameters originalModelParameters = ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)model).Model as LinearRegressionModelParameters; //Exception:System.InvalidCastException
```

> The object of the type
>   Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1[Microsoft.ML.Data.RegressionPredictionTransformer`1[Microsoft.ML.Trainers.FastTree.FastTreeRegressionModelParameters]]
>   can not be converted to
>   Microsoft.ML.ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer`1[System.Object]

How to access the model parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that your `model` object isn't a `ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer`, but instead it is a `TransformerChain` object (i.e. a chain of transformers), where the `LastTransformer` is the "prediction transformer".

So to fix this, first cast your `model` to `TransformerChain<RegressionPredictionTransformer<FastTreeRegressionModelParameters>>`, then you can get `LastTransformer`, which will return the `RegressionPredictionTransformer<FastTreeRegressionModelParameters>`, from there you can get the `Model` property.

If you don't happen to know at compile time which concrete type of transformer the TransformerChain will contain, you can cast `model` to `IEnumerable<ITransformer>` and get the `.Last()` transformer in the chain. That you can cast to `ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>` in order to get the `Model` property.

```cs
    ITransformer model = ...;
    IEnumerable<ITransformer> chain = model as IEnumerable<ITransformer>;

    ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object> predictionTransformer =
        chain.Last() as ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>;

    object modelParameters = predictionTransformer.Model;
```

From there you can cast `modelParameters` to whatever specific `ModelParameters` class it happens to be.

Note: from your exception message, it doesn't appear you are training a linear regression model, but instead a fast tree model. Tree-based models won't be able to be casted as `LinearRegressionModelParameters` as so you won't see bias and weights, but instead you will see tree information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it so much!
The modelParameters does contain 2 weights and a bias, shouldnt one of the weights be the bias?

Comment: I do realize that actopozipc most probably have already found the answer for his question, but for future generations here is a good link about what "bias" is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499936/2731639