# keras convnet 1d has bias although activation=none

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, bias-neuron

i have a convoutional neuronal network with keras:

```
 x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 65, padding='same', strides=2,activation=None)(input)
```

The input has the size `(8192,1)`

if i check my model summary, the layer has following properties,
output shape and params:

```
 (None, 4096, 128)    8448
```

Here how to calculate the params:

```
Input I x I x C
Filter F x F (x K) // K times applied
Parameters (F x F x C + 1) x K // where +1 bias per filter, and K is the number of filters
```

i calculated the params -> `(65 x 1 x 1 + 1) x 128` that gave me exact 8448. But i dont understand why the bias is inside it? I have activation=None.

[here](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) I read:

> If `use_bias` is True, a bias vector is created and added to the
>   outputs. Finally, if `activation is not None`, it is applied to the
>   outputs as well.

I have not set bias to true and activation to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `use_bias` is set to `True` by default, so this is the simple reason why your parameter count does not match. Activation also does not affect the use of biases.

Comment: ok thats easy :D is it even useful to have a bias without activation function?

Comment: @Khan My question already mentions that there is no relation between bias and activation functions

Comment: as it is here mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/what-is-the-role-of-the-bias-in-neural-networks  the bias can shift the activation function to left or right, could you give me an small explanation what is meant by that?