# What are free members w0 of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

In perceptron learning problems, we need to choose such w0,w1,w2,…,wn so that sign (σ (w0 + w1⋅x1 + w2⋅x2 +… + wn⋅xn))
But I do not understand where to get this free member w0. How to form it?

Comment: You don't get it "from" anywhere, you choose it like any other `w_i` value.

Comment: @Progman randomly? Why is it needed then?

Comment: Check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/what-is-the-role-of-the-bias-in-neural-networks why you need a bias value, which does not depend on any input value.