# toolbox in matlab

Tags: neural-network, matlab

I have downloaded the matlab software and now i want to use the neural network toolbox?/How do I access the toolbox??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, toolboxes are an additional piece you need to buy separately of the Matlab software. Usually, they cost LOTS of $$$.

Once you download the toolbox, it should be automatically installed by the installer and you can call its functions simply as you will call a native Matlab function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429290/neural-network-using-matlab

Plz go to this link and help in getting done with my problem.

Comment: @Shilpa - Simulink, like most of the other toolboxes is a product you should buy separately. As for your problem, my familiarity with Neural Networks is close to zero. I see, though, that you accepted one of the answers given in that thread. If my answer here satisfies you, you should mark it as accepted as well. If not, let me know what else you want to know.

Comment: @Shilpa - if you have Simulink installed then you definitely can use it to solve your problem, but you should ask yourself IF it is the right tool for that. Consider that Simulink was created to perform time-simulations of dynamic systems. It is given many tools for solving many types of problems, but if your problem is static in nature, I think plain Matlab is usually preferred.