# How can I convert C# code to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have this C# code and I am trying to convert it to MATLAB code.

```
float randomFloat()
{
    return (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}
int calculateOutput(float weights[], float x, float y)
{
    float sum = x * weights[0] + y * weights[1] + weights[2];
    return (sum >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I don't think we can use `float` and `int` in MATLAB. How do I change the code?

Comment: Also, have a look at the Matlab documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html. It explains rather well how the program works.

Comment: @ishamahajan: you seem to be using a different user, but if this related to your previous series of questions on neural networks, then the original code which is from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697243/help-with-perceptron/1714030#1714030 was actually in C\C++ not C# :)

Comment: Amro- U r very intelligent. But I am her rommie- Isha

Comment: I and shilpa were trying to do 1 layer of neural network but as we are not supposed to do using neural toolbox, its getting difficult for us.Do you have the pseudo code for it?or I should directly use the eg. that you told us and change it completlty into matlab? would it work?

Comment: if by 1-layer NN you mean a perceptron, then it should be straightforward to implement the *delta rule* for learning the weights (just like the C code I linked to). Otherwise if your goal is a full feed-forward multilayer perceptron, then its a bit more involved, and I suggest you refer to your textbook to understand the theory first before jumping to code..

Comment: ya, I checked in the book and it is the same.A single layer neural network can represent Y = AX + b, and the weights in the network will represent A and b at the end.But Can I get the pseudo code for it so that I can easily implement it

Comment: Amro ....can u see my other question that I posted today...I am doing so many mistakes that it is getting diificult to debug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first one is simply: `rand()`

the second function can be written as:

```
if ( [x y 1]*w(:) >=0 )
  result = 1;
else
  result = -1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function [`rand()`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) already does what you're trying to do with `randomFloat()`.

For `calculateOutput` you can use something fairly similar to what you've got, but as you say you don't need to declare types:

```
function result = calculateOutput (weights, x, y)
s = x * weights(1) + y * weights(2) + weights(3);
if s >= 0
    result = 1;
else
    result = -1;
end
end
```

Note that matlab vectors are one-based, so you need to adjust the indexing.

If you want to generalise this to arbitrary vectors it would make sense to "vectorize" it, but for this simple case a straight translation like this should be fine.