# matlab syntax errors in single layer neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have to implement a single layer neural network or perceptron.For this,  I have 2 files data sets , one for the input and one for the output.I have to do this in matlab without using neural toolbox.The format of 2 files is given below.

```
 In:
    0.832 64.643
    0.818 78.843
    1.776 45.049
    0.597 88.302
    1.412 63.458


Out:
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 0 1
```

The target output is "1 for a particular class that the corresponding input belongs to and "0 for the remaining 2 outputs.

I tried to do this, But it is not working for me.

```
load in.data
load out.data
x = in(:1);
y = in(:2);

learning rate = 0.2;
max_iteration = 50;

function result = calculateOutput(weights,x, y)
s = x*(weights(1) +weight(2) +weight(3));
if s>=0
 result = 1
else:
 result = -1
end
end

Count = length(x);
weights[0] = rand();
weights[1] = rand();
weights[2] = rand();

iter = 0;
do {
  iter++;
  globalerror = 0;
  for(p=0; p<count;p++){
    output = calculateoutput(weights,x[p],y[p]);
    localerror = output[p] - output
    weights[0]+= learningrate *localerror*x[p];
    weights[1]+= learningrate *localerror*y[p];
    weights[2]+= learningrate *localerror;
    globalerror +=(localerror*localerror);
   }
}while(globalerror != 0 && iter <= max_iteration);
```

Where is the mistake in this algorithm??

I am referring the example given in the link below:-

[Perceptron learning algorithm not converging to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697243/help-with-perceptron)

Comment: It's not an algorithm bug (yet). It is a syntax error `Count ≢ count`

Comment: It is clear from your code that you are not ready to attempt a complete solution all at once. I would recommend you start from a pseudocode algorithm and incrementally and independently implement  each step. If you don't know how to write a loop or increment a variable, attempting to write a complete program is not a productive learning experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a list of what I see wrong:

*deep breath*

- The indexing syntax `(:1)` is incorrect. Perhaps you mean `(:,1)` as in "all rows of column 1".
- There is no such thing as a do...while loop in MATLAB. Only [FOR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) and [WHILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/while.html) loops. Also, your for loop is defined wrong. MATLAB has a different syntax for that.
- There are no `++` or `+=` operators in MATLAB.
- The ["not equal" operator](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html#f0-38145) in MATLAB is `~=`, not `!=`.
- [Indexing of vectors and matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html) needs to be done with parentheses `()`, not square brackets `[]`.
- Is all of this inside a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/function.html) or a [script](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/script.html)? You can not define functions, namely `calculateOutput`, in a script. You would have to put that in its own m-file `calculateOutput.m`. If all of the code is actually inside a larger function, then `calculateOutput` is a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) and should work fine (assuming you have ended the larger enclosing function with an `end`).
- You have a number of apparent typos for variable names:

  - `weight` vs. `weights` (as per [phoffer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445484/matlab-syntax-errors-in-single-layer-neural-network/3445550#3445550))
  - `Count` vs. `count` (MATLAB is case-sensitive)
  - `calculateOutput` vs. `calculateoutput` (again, case-sensitivity)
  - `learning rate` vs. `learningrate` (variables can't have spaces in them)

*heavy exhale* ;)

In short, it needs quite a bit of work.

Comment: If calculateOutput is a nested function, the main function needs to be closed with an `end`

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks, I made that more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

On line #10, you have `weights(1) +weight(2) +weight(3)`; but the rest of the code has `weights` with an `s`.

EDIT:  Also, MATLAB does not have the `++` operator; your `for` loop will cause an error. In MATLAB, construct a `for` loop like this:

```
for p=0:count
    blah blah blah
end
```

Also, MATLAB does not use the `+=` operator either, as Jonas pointed out in his code. You need to do this:

`weights(0) = weights(0) + learningrate * localerror * x(p)`

Answer (score 1):

The main mistake is that this is not written using Matlab syntax. Here is an attempt to do what I think you were trying to do.

Unfortunately, there is a fundamental problem with your algorithm (see comments in the code). Also, I think you should have a look at the very good Matlab documentation. Reading the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html) will tell you quickly how you format this.

```
function neuralNetwork

%# load data
load in.data
load out.data
x = in(:,1);
y = in(:,2);

%# set constants
learningrate = 0.2;
max_iteration = 50;

% initialize parameters
count = length(x);
weights = rand(1,3); % creates a 1-by-3 array with random weights

iter = 0;
while globalerror ~= 0 && iter <= max_iteration
  iter = iter + 1;
  globalerror = 0;
  for p = 1:count
    output = calculateOutput(weights,x(p),y(p));

    %# the following line(s) cannot possibly work
    %# output is not a vector, since the previous line
    %# assigns it to a scalar
    %# Also, arrays are accessed with parentheses
    %# and indexing starts at 1
    %# and there is no += operator in Matlab
    localerror = output[p] - output
    weights[0]+= learningrate *localerror*x[p];
    weights[1]+= learningrate *localerror*y[p];
    weights[2]+= learningrate *localerror;
    globalerror +=(localerror*localerror);
end %# for-loop
end %# while-loop


%# subfunctions in Matlab are put at the end of the file
function result = calculateOutput(weights,x, y)
s = x*(weights(1) +weight(2) +weight(3));
if s>=0
 result = 1
else:
 result = -1
end
end
```

Comment: Great idea doing a rewrite of it, but MATLAB does not use `+=` either. You have to do `weights[0] = weights[0] + learningrate * localerror * x[p]`

Comment: SORRY, I completely read over the last part of your comment block. I moved the comment to my answer and credited you.