# problem in understanding the code

Tags: c++

```
i = 0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%f %f %d", &x[i], &y[i], &outputs[i]) != EOF) {
    if (outputs[i] == 0) {
        outputs[i] = -1;
    }
    i++;
}
patternCount = i;
```

I dont understand the meaning of this line from the above code:

```
if (outputs[i] == 0) {
        outputs[i] = -1;
```

What does it represent. The Output is a matrix or vector.??

The refrence of the code is:
[Perceptron learning algorithm not converging to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697243/help-with-perceptron)

```
I have a output file that has 3 columns:

1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

So it a vector file??

Comment: I don't understand how Matlab and C++ can be in the same question....

Comment: It is a `1-D` array, which is like a vector in math. It changes `v_i` where `v` is the vector and `i` is the index.

Comment: oh sorry...i shud remove that tag now..

Comment: but why, output[i] = 0 => output[i] = -1???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*outputs* is defined as a one-dimensional array containing integer values..

```
float x[208], y[208];
int outputs[208];
```

Each index in the array can be seen as corresponding to a line read in the [data](http://neuron-ai.tuke.sk/~vascak/predmety/UI/test1.txt) file.

```
  i       x              y      outputs
  --------------------------------------
  0 | -8.818681   3.025210     1
  1 |  3.653846  -2.969188     0
  2 |  ...           ...           .
 .. |  ...           ...           .
208 | -6.565934  -4.649860     1
```

Where if *i* == 0 then

```
x[0]       == -8.818681
y[0]       == 3.025210
outputs[0] == 1
```

The wonderful code and information posted by user *Amro* explain the limits and function of *outputs*.

> **"**...bias term, i.e. a third weight component connected to an input of value 1. (+1/-1)
>   **"**

Values for *outputs* in the data file have been assigned one/zero values.
Therefore the code in question checks to see if the value for *outputs* read in from the file is equal to zero and re-assigns to a -1.

```
if (outputs[i] == 0)
    outputs[i] = -1;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454794/matlab-programming-for-perceptron---vcan u help me in this question too

Comment: I would like to help, but I don't know anything about Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can tell, the code is reading from a file, and the file is supposed to have a repeated pattern, each pattern consists of 3 numbers.

Your loop copy the first number in each pattern to x, the second to y, and the last to outputs. However whenever the third number is a zero, it is changed to -1.

patternCount will store the number of pattern read in the file

Answer (score 2):

A perceptron is a term from artificial intelligence/neural networks. It operates in much the same way as a single neuron is supposed to operate in the brain.

It has a number of inputs and a single output.

All this file is doing is specifying what the output should be for a given set of inputs. That's why the `x/y` and `output` are named differently.

As to why it's morphing the output from 0 to -1 (that's all it's doing by the way: changing zeros in the third file column into negative one), I'm not sure. The outputs of perceptrons almost invariably feed into other perceptrons so passing a -1 to something that expects 0 or 1 is an ... interesting ... idea.

Comment: thanks....can u see my other question that I posted now...I need help in that question very badly.

Comment: I'd love to help out, @ishamahajan, but I don't know Matlab unfortunately.