# Pybrain basic network organization questions

Tags: python, pybrain

I've started building some networks in Pybrain and having a lot of fun.  I'm  not entirely thrilled with the docs so I've built small, simple nets and played with them to discern how the class structure and data flow works.

I have a few questions:

Setup:

---

```
n = FeedForwardNetwork()

inLayer = LinearLayer(1, name = 'Input node')
hiddenLayer = LinearLayer(1, name = 'Hidden node')
outLayer = LinearLayer(1, name = 'Output node')

n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)
```

---

1) When you execute the "addInputModule" method, are the nodes in that layer automatically restricted to one input each? Is there any way to have more than one?

2) It seems I cannot create a NN of one node with 4 inputs and 1 output....looks like I MUST use at least 2 nodes for any NN, because the weights are associated with the edge (i.e. connection)  class. And if I have 4 inputs, I must have 4 nodes in the InputModule....

```
Do I have this right?
```

3) In the above code snippet, what are the default Threshold Functions for each node in each layer?  How can I display what the T.F.'s are?

4) Is there any documentation that describes all the available inputs for each class method?

Thanks!

Gregg

Answer (score 1):

Your question is to broad, and is abit offtopic for this reason. Nonetheless, I'll try to address some of your issues.

- You have to add connections between layers with `n.addConnection`
- A node represents an input, so for 4 input - 1 output NN you need an input layer with 4 neurons, see below. Note that 1 output means that this is simply a yes-no classifier, as it can predict whether a sample belong to exactly one class. 4 inputs means that NN classifies samples with 4 features (i.e. vectors in 4d space)

*NN with 4 inputs and 1 output:*

```
from pybrain import structure

fnn  = structure.FeedForwardNetwork()
in_layer = LinearLayer(4, name = 'Input node')
out_layer = LinearLayer(1, name = 'Output node')

fnn.addInputModule(in_layer)
fnn.addOutputModule(out_layer)
fnn.addConnection(structure.FullConnection(in_layer, out_layer))
```

- About neuron's [treshold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563482/1265154)
- PyBrain is [well documented](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/fnn.html)